# Google Chrome cache after updating / Developer Dashboard

Tags: css, google-chrome, caching, developer-tools

Each Google Chrome update brings many advantages but also many disadvantages for the developer. Today, I do not know whether it was because of the update, I noticed that chrome caches everything successively without disassembling. Here is an example:

I develop the site as usual. Style sheets, js, etc. When I make some changes to stylesheet file, respectively, it should be changed after reloading the page, or so it was until recently. Now I have to clear the cache (CTRL + SHIFT + i => Network => Disable cache, but there is little notice *While DevTools is open*). The question is: Can I return everything as it once was? When I made changes to the stylesheet file, can they take effect after usual page reloading, instead of permanently opening the developer dashboard?

Comment: I noticed that too today, something changed with cahching. Optionally, you can refresh page with CTRL+SHIFT+r.

Answer (score 0):

You can download older version of Chrome/Chromium by using the instructions listed here: https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium.

The SO question [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development) deals with an identical issue. In particular, you'll find a link for the Chrome extension **Cache Killer** which may allow you to develop more easily while still getting the updates your users will receive.